# How to disable ANR Watchdog when generating Trace Logs for Profiling after instrumenting my App?

Tags: android, performance, profiling, android-anr-dialog

Currently trying to obtain profile trace logs files for a huge Android app, that we have instrumented on MyApplication class, following the [documentation about instrumenting my app to get trace logs](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/generate-trace-logs#java).

We are trying to dig into what happens when our app is initialized and Dagger2 creates the object graph when the app is started.

A cold startup can take a few seconds normally, the issue I have is that when I add the Debug traces, it dramatically slows down the initialization of the app, making it crash with an ANR message.

```
    com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError: Application Not Responding
    Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: main (state = RUNNABLE)
```

I would like to know if there is a way to prevent the Android OS from crashing my app when it blocks for a long period of time, or to at least increase the ANR threshold.

Any help or tips are welcome. Thanks!

For further context, this is roughly what I am doing in my MyApplication.class:

```
public void onCreate() {
   super.onCreate();

   Debug.startMethodTracing("MyApp_onCreate()");

   injectSelf();
   AppInit.initApp(this);

   Debug.stopMethodTracing();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it turns out we have our own `ANRWatchDogManager` which I wasn't aware of, where I can extend the limit.

```
public class ANRWatchDogManager implements ANRWatchDog.ANRListener {
```

Somewhere in that class:

```
    public void startANRWatchDog() {
        final int timeoutInterval = isDebugBuild() && isEmulator()
                ? ANR_INCREASED_TIMEOUT
                : ANR_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;
        new ANRWatchDog(timeoutInterval).setANRListener(this).start();
    }
```